# How to setState with a promise before render?

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have promise in props: `this.props.getProfile()` and i want to set response value in promise into state before render()

i have tried with `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` and `getDerivedStateFromProps` but it always response a promise pending.

Here is my try with `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`:

```
    UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({profile: this.getProfile()})
    }
    getProfile=()=>{
        return this.props.getProfile()
        .then(res =>{
            if (res.type === 'ERROR_MESSAGE') {
                return null;
            }
            return res.payload
        });
    }
```

Here is my try with `getDerivedStateFromProps`:

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps (props, state){
        let a = props.getProfile()
        .then(res =>{
            if (res.type === 'ERROR_MESSAGE') {
                return null;
            }
            return res.payload
        });
        console.log(a);
        if(a.profile !== state.profile)
            return {profile: a};
    }
```

Comment: Resolve the promise before rendering the component instead of doing it within the component. That way you don't supply a promise as a prop, but the final value ready for render.

Comment: How can i do it, my props just is a axios request, not a component

Answer (score 0):

you might think that at a given promise once you return something  inside `then` method you would get that value right away back, when actually you are returning other promise. to solve that you have 2 standard approaches, use `async/await` or chain another `then` to the promise.

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is not meant for data fetch as you can see a good discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13541)

**async\await**

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const profile = await this.props.getProfile()
  this.setState({ profile })
}
```

**promise chaining**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props
    .getProfile()
    .then(profile => this.setState({ profile }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but `componentDidMount()` is after render(), and .then just resolve after rendering is done. My question is setState before `render()`

Comment: You can't do that with an async method call. You are even trying to use unsafe deprecated methods for that, which is bad. The proper way is to use didmount and conditional render given if you status is fetched. or call fetch at parent and conditional render your child once you fetch the status. The link I posted is with responses of react 's leader creator, that explicit tells not to use these methods for that. I'm sorry but I I can't give you an answer that violates react' s principles.